# A route is not covered in layout component, but still renders layout in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm having to trouble making a route without layout component. Please check my code first.

```js
// App.js

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <QuizBoxContainer>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/' element={<QuizSelect />} />
            <Route path='quiz-for/:language' element={<QuizCard />} />
            <Route path='result' element={<ResultPage />} />
          </Routes>
        </QuizBoxContainer>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='wrong-answer' element={<WrongAnswer />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

In the code, `<QuizBoxContainer>` is the layout component.

**What I was trying to do is making another path,**

```
<Routes>
   <Route path='wrong-answer' element={<WrongAnswer />} />
</Routes>
```

**outside of `<QuizBoxContainer>` so I can use another layout on this component.**

However, when I go to WrongAnswer,

[image]

**It still renders.**

What is wrong with my code, and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The is because the `QuizBoxContainer` layout wrapper component is not rendered on any route, it's ***always*** rendered.

## Solution

Move `QuizBoxContainer` into a [layout route](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes). You'll need to update `QuizBoxContainer` so it renders an `Outlet` component instead of the `children` prop.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const QuizBoxContainer = () => {
  ...

  return (
    ... quiz container layout/styling ...
    <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    ...
  );
};
```

Render `QuizBoxContainer` on a layout route wrapping the routes you want to render within it, render the wrong answer route outside the layout route.

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <main>
        <Routes>
          <Route element={<QuizBoxContainer />}>
            <Route path='/' element={<QuizSelect />} />
            <Route path='quiz-for/:language' element={<QuizCard />} />
            <Route path='result' element={<ResultPage />} />
          </Route>
          <Route path='wrong-answer' element={<WrongAnswer />} />
        </Routes>
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Wow. This is totally amazing. I didn't have any idea about this way. Thank you Drew. You saved my life.